# Fixed tumblr heading?

Tags: css

so this is the first theme I've "made",and I'm not amazing with code. My vision for this theme is a header with the title and links, and footer with the description, and the posts with no margins in a grid in the middle. I have everything where I want it to be, and I know how to fix the text (keep it from scrolling away with the posts), but I don't know how to add the background, because right now you can't see the text through the posts. I want a white bar to stay behind the header and footer at all times so that you can see the text in the header and footer at all times. I've tried so many different codes, I've even looked at the codes of other themes that have this sort of effect and copied parts of it to emulate it, but nothing has worked. If you need an example of what I want, picture a header and footer like [this](http://adventurepremium.tumblr.com/) fixed header with my blog (my url is allapologys). Please help me, this is drving me crazy!!

I feel really really stupid, but I made one of those jsfiddle things but is says to the link in my post, I need to put in code? What code should I put in? Surely not the whole thing, right? Ugh I'm an idiot, I know. Please don't make fun of me :P.

Comment: add your markup and css, better if you can provide a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: answer is given. check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through your website. Lots of thing you have to do. First change the first two div structure like this. Also Update `#title` and `#links` div CSS like below.

**HTML**

```
 <div style="position:fixed; top:0; left:0; width:100%;background:#ccc;z-index:100;">
   <div id="title">
     <b><a href="/" title="Home">All Apologys</a></b>
   </div>

 <div id="links">
  <a href="/favs">Favorite Blogs</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; 
  <a href="/favtv">Favorite TV Shows</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; 
  <a href="/favmovies">Favorite Movies</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; 
  <a href="/favmusic">Favorite Music</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; 
  <a href="/ask">ASK</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; 
  <a href="http://allapologys.tumblr.com/themes">theme</a>
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 #title
{
 text-transform:uppercase;
 /* position:fixed */
 z-index:1;
 float:left;
 overflow:hidden;
/* top:25px;
left: 10px; */
}

#links
{
 position:absolute;
 padding:10px;
 z-index:2;
 float:left;
 overflow:hidden;
 /*margin-top:-50px;
 margin-left:575px;*/
 bottom:10px;
 right:250px;
}
```

Comment: okay. I replaced the #links and #title with your code. Where am I supposed to put the first one (the html one)? Again, I'm sorry like I said I'm pretty new... Thanks so much for your patience and help!!

Comment: that is the html. instead of "#title" and "#links" div you need to replace with it.